# Atomic inc of multiple mongoid hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a Mongoid model with a hash field that looks like this:

```
class DimensionStat
 include ::Mongoid::Document
 include ::Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :data, type: Hash

 attr_accessible :data
end
```

I pretend on runtime fill data with something like

```
data: {
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    ...
}
```

I need to perform increments on multiple keys atomically such as:

```
'a' => -1,
'b' => 5
```

Somewhere I found that:

```
instance.collection.find(_id: my_id).update("$inc" => {'data.a' => -1,
'data.b' => 5})
```

will do the trick but it doesn't, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I'm using mongoid 3.1.6

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I do that sort of thing all the time and it works fine. What does `data` look like inside that document inside MongoDB? BTW, `:$inc` is a valid symbol so you can say `:$inc => { ... }` if you'd like.

Comment: I'm getting empty hashes everytime, no matter what

Comment: But what does `data` look like inside MongoDB *before* you try to do anything to it?

Comment: It does not exists on the document, it does not get dynamically created with mongoid when trying to update this field?

Comment: No, MongoDB won't autovivify the hash for you. You use `:$inc` to increments things that are already there.

Comment: @mu is too short field :data, type: Hash, default: {}, worked, put it as an answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.inc` method works perfectly with non-existing keys, but the document is not automatically refreshed from the database. Try:

```
dimension_stat.inc('data.a' => -1, 'data.b' => 5)
puts dimension_stat.data['a'] # not changed
dimension_stat.reload
puts dimension_stat.data['a'] # changed
```

you will see that the counters have changed.